# Cannot install Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am running Windows 8.1, I have installed Visual Studio 2010 and when I try to install the service pack from Windows Update I get the following message[image]

Anyone run into this before and know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue was but I went a head and downloaded the service pack installer from MSDN and it installed with no issues.